# Sort algorithm is not working with my template manipulated with pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written three templates in the following code snipet. There is a problem that Input and Display functions are working corectly but Sort function is not working quite. There is some logical problem in code but I couldnt found it. Please help me in locating and also resolving it. The program executes very well but when I input data it somehow goes to infinite loop i think and everything in it seems stop.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void input(T* &array, int limit){
    array = new T[limit];
    T* start = array;
    T* beyond = &start[limit];

    while(start != beyond){
        cout<<"\nEnter: ";
        cin>>*start;
        start++;
    }
}


template<typename T>
void sort(T* array, int limit){
    T hold;
    T* start = array, *beyond = &start[limit];
    T* Next = &start[1];

    for(int j=0; j<limit-1; j++){
        while((start != beyond) || (Next != beyond)){
            if(start>Next){
                    hold=*start;
                    start=Next;
                    *Next=hold;
                    start++;
                    Next++;
            }
        }
    }


}



template<typename T>
void display(T* start, int limit){
    T* beyond = &start[limit];
    cout<<"\nAfter Sorting: "<<endl;

    while(start != beyond){
        cout<<*start<<"\t";
        start++;
    }
}

int main(){
    int* x=NULL;
    float* y=NULL;
    char* z=NULL;
    int size;

    cout<<"Enter the number of elements: ";
    cin>>size;

    cout<<"\nEnter integer values:";
    input<int>(x, size);
    sort<int>(x, size);
    display<int>(x, size);


    cout<<"\nEnter floating values:";
    input<float>(y, size);
    sort<float>(y, size);
    display<float>(y, size);

    cout<<"\nEnter character values:";
    input<char>(z, size);
    sort<char>(z, size);
    display<char>(z, size);

    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I am mistaken, but are you the one who asked a similar question a while ago?

Comment: actually this is my first question

Comment: Hmm..strange...I have seen a question with 3 templates and what not, tagged with `C` a while ago.... dunno...

Comment: i dont know. may be someone else.

Comment: `start>Next` compares two pointers. It will never be true.

Comment: Avoid to use `using namespace std;` and using name that may clash with it. (as `std::sort` that you may use).

Comment: @molbdnilo, not true - A pointer is a integer memory address, one can be higher or lower than another.

Comment: @JohnBargman `Next` is intialised to `&start[1]`. Neither is modified unless `start > Next`. Thus, `start > Next` will never be true.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm sorry I misunderstood - I thought you where stating that "the comparison is never true because you are using pointers", Rather than "you are using pointers, and the comparison will never be true"

Comment: Did you tried using a debugger? And what is the intended sorting order?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider using standard libraries.

Most Problems have been solved in the past and the a lot of them are so basic that you can find a standard implementation for it.

The best you can hope for when re implementing a solution is to not write erroneous code. The standards are not only well tested, when reading code you know a lot about the functionality just by looking at it. If you read a custom implementation you have to check what it does. If you read a standard implementation being used you already know exactly what it does.

Here is a snippet that would sort your code in a similar fashion as above but using a standard implementation.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

template<typename T>
void input(string msg, T &element)
{
    cout << msg;
    cin >> element;
}

template<typename T>
void display(string label, const vector<T> & v)
{
    cout << label;
    for (const T & t : v)
    {
        cout << " ";
        cout << t;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> in;
    int size;

    cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
    cin >> size;
    in.reserve(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        int temp;
        input("Input Number: ", temp);
        in.emplace_back(temp);
    }

    //http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort
    display("before sorting", in);
    std::sort(in.begin(), in.end(), std::greater<int>());
    display("after sort greater", in);
    std::sort(in.begin(), in.end(), std::less<int>());
    display("after sort less", in);

    //in Visual Studio hit (CTRL + F5) to start with a pause after execution ends
}
```

If you somehow have to implement a sort function that iterates through pointers. Here is an inefficient version:

```
template<typename T>
void sort(T* array, int limit)
{
    T* start = array;
    T* end = start + limit;

    for (T* outer = start; outer < end; ++outer)
    {
        for (T* inner = start; inner < end; ++inner)
        {
            if (*outer > *inner)
            {
                T hold = *inner;
                *inner = *outer;
                *outer = hold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote? If this is supposed to be Production Code using sort is an excellent idea. If this is Homework my answer is not helping but then again homework should not be put up as "solve my homework".

Comment: I didnt downvote, but usually I do downvote "code only" answers.

Comment: @tobi303 Ah, that may actually be it. I will add some context. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your trying to do this using templates. But here's some bad things.

```
array = new T[limit];
```

Here you are allocating memory via new, but never deleting it - That is a serious error. Read up on [New and Delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) - You may want to consider using some like `std::shared_ptr<T> array (new T[limit], std::default_delete<T[]>())` to create a shared-pointer (`include <memory>` on any c++11 compiler)

```
while ((start != beyond) || (Next != beyond)) {
        if (start>Next) {
```

This will loop forever (and I believe is the cause of your problem), you only increment start when start is greater than next, However as start is lower than next, that will never happen!

Eg:
start = 0x0000A and next = 0x0000C, Start is lower than next, thus you **never enter the if statement** and `start++` never happens.

**advice:**

As others have said, using standard libraries is a REALLY good idea.

Trying to sort data in this way, using pointers and arrays is a *very bad idea*, in modern C++ using new and delete is pretty much a taboo (at least where I work ;-).

Don't use `namespace std;`, ever.

Comment: Sir may you please edit the sort function for me so that I clearly understand it. thanks

Comment: @SabaNazPoetess Actually you should edit your question, so that we can understand how you want to sort. Which order should the elements have after sorting?

Comment: I agree with @tobi303, if you show us what your trying to achieve, we can help much better.